# Multiple Custom Cells Placement in Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, modulo, custom-cell

I'm having a problem getting my custom cells placed where I want them in my table view. I wouldn't be surprised if there's an easy solution to this as I'm a novice.

The first cell is a "day" cell. I need 7 of those, then one "week" cell. And then repeat.

I thought I could use modulo to get the 8th cell for the week and I would be set! Unfortunately, that makes the first index a weekly cell, which is not what I want. So I put index.row != 0 in the condition, like this:

```
if (indexPath.row%8 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0) {
        weeklyCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Week" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // some code to add content to the cell
        return weeklyCell;
} else {
// dayCell code
}
```

But this gives me the problem of having 8 days before the first week cell appears. After that first week cell, it works great. 7 days, one week cell, etc.

Essentially I need indexPath.row from 0-6 for dayCell, 7 for weekCell, 8-14 for dayCell, 15 for weekCell, etc.

I can't seem to figure this out how to do this with modulo, or any other way. No similar SO question addresses my problem.

A solution would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work,

```
if ((indexPath.row + 1) %8 == 0) {
        weeklyCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Week" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // some code to add content to the cell
        return weeklyCell;
} else {
// dayCell code
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 23 seconds. :D

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
BOOL isWeekCell = (indexPath.row % 8) == 7;
```

Comment: Sorry to not give you the best answer. I just don't understand how BOOL can be true before indexPath.row reaches 15, to give a remainder of 7

Comment: For the first 7 rows, row % 8 == 0 to 6 (remember the first row is row 0)  For the 8th row, row is 7, 7 % 8 = 7.  For rows 8-15, the sequence just repeats, that's the nature of the modulo operator.

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't understand how modulo works. Now I get it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
if (indexPath.row%8 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0)
```

With:

```
if (indexPath.row+1%8 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0)
```

I think this will solve the issue.